# Custom Script Extension for Linux - Not able to run ora2pg command

Tags: linux, azure, perl, ora2pg

I am new to Azure.

We have created one small POC in which I need to select the VM name and Resource group name in which that VM is present. And then I need to mention the command which I need to execute and then click on execute button which will execute the command.

Now what I have done, I have created one script in linux in which I have given some ora2pg commands. So what is happening when I am trying to run that script directly on VM by passing some parameter, it is working fine without any error.

But same script when I am trying to run through that the POC which I created (by giving VM name, Resource group name and then passing the command which I want to execute) it is giving this error -

> Enable succeeded: [stdout] Schema Name : OT Conversation of tables for
> OT schema started Conversation of views for OT schema started
> Conversation of package for OT schema started Conversation of sequence
> for OT schema started Conversation of type for OT schema started
> Conversation of trigger for OT schema started Conversation of function
> for OT schema started Conversation of procedure for OT schema started
> Successfully copied to OT_SCHEMA [stderr] install_driver(Oracle)
> failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so'
> for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line
> 193. at (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3. Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.
> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
> '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
> DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
> (eval 14) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 1660.

Note - My Linux VM is in Azure and it is using Custom script for linux extension to run all the commands. I have moved my script to bin folder so that by passing only the name it will run the script.

I have mention following things in env path in linux -

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/pgsql-12/bin/
```

My perl version is 5.26

As I said everything is working fine when I am trying to run from VM, but when I trying to run through my POC it is giving that issue.

Can anyone please help me with the issue like where I am lagging?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' ` : Can you check if that file exists or not?

Comment: Thank you @HåkonHægland for your reply. I think I have installed only oracle client thats why I dont have that file. But if thats not really the case then can u please help me out?!

Comment: So when running the script from the VM it works fine? Then try to locate the file `Oracle.so` on the VM. Try run `perl -MDBD::Oracle -E'say $INC{"DBD/Oracle.pm"}'`

Comment: Thank you @HåkonHægland for your reply. Yes when I am trying to run the script from from VM, its working fine. And I ran the command provided by you, after running I am getting something like this - /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBD/Oracle.pm

Comment: So then there is also a file `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so` on the VM ?

Comment: Yes @HåkonHægland , I am having that file.

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure, so to clarify: when you are running the script with Azure it is using a different VM (than the one on which you have the `.so` file) ?

Comment: No same VM it is using to run script. I tested with other small scripts in which I have given command to create file and it ran fine and created file also.

Comment: Strange.. Does this script give an error: `perl -MDBD::Oracle -E'say $INC{"DBD/Oracle.pm"}'` when you run it with Azure ?

Comment: No @HåkonHægland, I didnt got any error when I am running "perl -MDBD::Oracle -E'say $INC{"DBD/Oracle.pm"}' , from Azure. I am getting output as - "Enable succeeded: [stdout] /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBD/Oracle.pm [stderr]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223001/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-saurabh704).

Comment: Add an answer to display the solution if you solved the problem.